# JavaScript : Altering a series every Nth time (start with 1 always)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a component `<Card>` which takes a parameter `alter` and renders the result based on the `alter` value.

If `alter` is 0 it renders in orange color and if alter is 1 it renders in blue color.

I am rendering results in grid as shown below:

```
Orange       Blue
Blue         Orange
Orange       Blue
```

My input function looks like this:

```
const getAlterParam = (index:number) => {
    return alter;
}
```

The function should behave like this:

```
input: 0 output: 1
input: 1 output: 0 [Negation of previous value] [Count = 1]
input: 2 output: 0 [Negation of first value] [Count = 2]
input: 3 output: 1 [Altering the value after N = 2] [Count = 1]
input: 4 output: 1 [Count = 2]
input: 5 output: 0 [Altering the value after N = 2] [Count = 1]
input: 6 output: 0 [Count = 2]
input: 7 output: 1 [Altering the value after N = 2] [Count = 1]
...
```

Here's what I tried:

```
let count = 0;
let alter = 1;
const getAlterParam = () => {
    count++;
    if (count % 3 === 0) {
        alter = alter === 1 ? 0 : 1;
        count = 1;
    }
    return alter;
};
```

but the above code doesn't take index into consideration, it would generate the series when invoked in sequence. I need to link input and output somehow.

Comment: Could you provide a more thorough pseudocode for your function? I don't understand what it's meant to be doing. What is Count?

Comment: Hey @aurelienrichard thank you very much for the question. All I wanted to transform a series to 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1. I think sharpknife has suggested a solution which seems to be working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the pattern `1, 0, 0, 1` is repeating. We can use `index modulus 4` to generate the pattern.

```
//assuming index is a non-negative integer
const getAlterParam = (index) => {
    return (index % 4 == 0 || index % 4 == 3) ? 1 : 0;
};
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! I totally missed thinking this way! :)